# Add column to dataframe according to values in multiple dataframes in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `target` that contains columns `SNP` and `value`:

```
target <- data.frame("SNP" = c("rs2", "rs4", "rs6", "rs19", "rs8", "rs9"),
                     "value" = 1:6)
```

I have 3 other dataframes that contains columns `SNP` and `int` as a list:

```
ref1 <- data.frame("SNP" = c("rs1", "rs2", "rs8"), "int" = c(5, 7, 88))
ref2 <- data.frame("SNP" = c("rs9", "rs4", "rs3"), "int" = c(23, 4, 43))
ref3 <- data.frame("SNP" = c("rs10", "rs6", "rs5"), "int" = c(53, 22, 76))
mylist <- list(ref1, ref2, ref3)
```

I want to add a new column `int` for `target` whose values correspond to the `int` values of the ref1/2/3 with the same `SNP`. For example, the first `int` value for `target` should be 7 because row 2 of ref1 has `SNP` of rs2 and `int` of 7.

I tried the following code:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    target <- target %>%
                left_join(mylist[[i]], by = "SNP")
}
```

The matching was quick and successful. However, I was returned 3 new columns rather than 1, shown as below:
[image]

I then used the following code:

```
target[, "ref"] <- NA
for (i in 1:3) {
    common <- Reduce(intersect, list(target$SNP, mylist[[i]]$SNP))

    tar.pos <- match(common, target$SNP)
    ref.pos <- match(common, mylist[[i]]$SNP)

    target$ref[tar.pos] <- mylist[[i]]$int[ref.pos]
}
```

In my real data, I have 22 ref dataframes with each have 1-6 MILLION rows. I would prefer to do the matching and joining ref by ref rather than merging all refs into one single large data. When I tried the second method above on my real data, I noted that the `match` function worked very slow. This is why I prefer some smart way of doing the work. I found left_join worked very fast even for my large data. Unfortunately, the output is not exactly what I want.

I wish to do the above work in a fast way, preferably in tidyverse. Is there any suggestion on how do revise the first coding method or any other smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If binding all data in `mylist` and merging to `target` takes too much memory, you can use `purrr::reduce` to merge one by one.

```
library(tidyverse)

reduce(mylist,
       ~ left_join(.x, .y, by = "SNP") %>%
         mutate(int = coalesce(int.x, int.y)) %>%
         select(-c(int.x, int.y)),
       .init = mutate(target, int = NA_real_))

#    SNP value int
# 1  rs2     1   7
# 2  rs4     2   4
# 3  rs6     3  22
# 4 rs19     4  NA
# 5  rs8     5  88
# 6  rs9     6  23
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can also do

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mylist) %>%
  right_join(target, by = "SNP")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `mylist` into one dataframe and then `merge` with `target`

```
merge(target, do.call(rbind, mylist), by = "SNP", all.x = TRUE)

#   SNP value int
#1 rs19     4  NA
#2  rs2     1   7
#3  rs4     2   4
#4  rs6     3  22
#5  rs8     5  88
#6  rs9     6  23
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(target, bind_rows(mylist), by = "SNP")
```

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mylist)[target, on = 'SNP']
```

Comment: Thank you. In my real data, I have 22 ref data with each having around 6 million rows. Binding rows would definitely work. But merging all ref for my real data takes too much memory. This is why I want to deal with it separately for each ref data. I will be able to delete each ref data after successful matching.

Comment: @Patrick Do you know it beforehand which element of `mylist` will have which data? Or you have to go through each one of them one by one to find the match?

Comment: Thank you. My `target` has a column named `chromosome`, which goes from 1 to 22. For each `ref` data, the `chromosome` value is fixed to one value. This is why I have 22 ref data. Would that be helpful for developing some quick method?

Comment: How does it reflect for the data you have shared? You can try the `data.table` version : `rbindlist(mylist)[target, on = 'SNP']`